# Downloading images from url in memory and creating zip archive in memory to send to the browser

Tags: python, django, zip

In my django project i need to send a zip file to the client side for download.This zip file would contain images downloaded from various url's.

Is it possible to download the images in memory without writing the image files to disk then add them to a zip file in memory itself,again not writing the zip file to disk and finally sending the zip file to the client for download ?

Im aware that urllib2 can be used for image downloads and zipfile for working with zip files but facing a problem with performing these operations in memory itself.So,some example for this would be really appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the file with urllib2.  Open a new ZipFile for writing (you'll need a StringIO object for this). Write the output from the url into ZilpFile.writestr.  Attach zip file to django response.

```
import urllib2
from StringIO import StringIO

url = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/foo.jpg')
f = StringIO()
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'w')
zip.writestr('foo.jpg', url.read())
response = HttpResponse(f.getvalue(), content_type="application/zip")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=foobar.zip'
return response
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But on the client side,im not getting the file save as dialog.I tried this in chrome browser.

Comment: What response is the server giving you?

Comment: I checked in the chrome debugger, in the response pane it shows some gibberish characters.The response headers are Connection:keep-alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=foobar.zip
Content-Type:application/zip
Date:Thu, 19 Apr 2012 21:19:18 GMT
P3p:CP="IDC CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"
Server:gunicorn/0.14.2
transfer-encoding:chunked

Comment: Im really sorry, i was making the request via ajax, my mistake :). Its working. Thanks a lot for ur help !! :)

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try this. Maybe its because I'm reading it from s3, I get the url open it with urllib2. But then when I try to use writestr() I get "TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'"

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, simply:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://..')
img_bytes = response.read()
```

and then use ZipFile.writestr to write these bytes into a file, inside the Zip you previously created passing a StringIO handler instead of a real file handler. When finished writing files, return this as HTTPResponse setting proper mimetype and content disposition.

But I wouldn't use the RAM for this. Why not use tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile?

Comment: I can't think of any good reason to write this out to disk unless he's zipping up an enormous amount of images and even then I'm not sure it would help much.  All you're doing is adding unnecessary disk io (which is far more likely to be the limiting factor on a web server)

Comment: It depends on user concurrency for that download operation. If he grabs photos on the fly from various links, this can take some time before the memory is cleared out. From Django docs: by default, if an uploaded file is smaller than 2.5 megabytes, Django will hold the entire contents of the upload in memory. So it depends on size and concurrency of usage, I guess.