# How to generate a Zip from a set of streams and producing a stream with the Zip data?

Tags: python, django, stream, zip

I have an app with manages a set of files, but those files are actually stored in Rackspace's CloudFiles, because most of the files will be ~100GB. I'm using the Cloudfile's TempURL feature to allow individual files, but sometimes, the user will want to download a set of files. But downloading all those files and generating a local Zip file is impossible since the server only have 40GB of disk space.

From the user view, I want to implement it the way GMail does when you get an email with several pictures: It gives you a link to download a Zip file with all the images in it, and the download is immediate.

How to accomplish this with Python/Django? I have found [ZipStream](https://github.com/SpiderOak/ZipStream) and looks promising because of the iterator output, but it still only accepts filepaths as arguments, and the `writestr` method would need to fetch all the file data at once (~100GB).

Answer (score 4):

Since **Python 3.5** it is possible to create zip chunks stream of huge files/folders. You can use the unseekable stream. So no need to use [ZipStream](https://github.com/SpiderOak/ZipStream) now.
See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55169752/5717886).

And live example here: https://repl.it/@IvanErgunov/zipfilegenerator

If you don't have filepath, but have chunks of bytes you can exclude `open(path, 'rb') as entry` from example and replace `iter(lambda: entry.read(16384), b'')` with your iterable of bytes. And prepare ZipInfo manually:

```
zinfo = ZipInfo(filename='any-name-of-your-non-existent-file', date_time=time.localtime(time.time())[:6])
zinfo.compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_STORED
# permissions:
if zinfo.filename[-1] == '/':
   # directory
   zinfo.external_attr = 0o40775 << 16   # drwxrwxr-x
   zinfo.external_attr |= 0x10           # MS-DOS directory flag
else:
   # file
   zinfo.external_attr = 0o600 << 16     # ?rw-------
```

You should also remember that the zipfile module writes chunks of its zipfile own size. So, if you send a piece of 512 bytes the stream will receive a piece of data only when and only with size the zipfile module decides to do it. It depends on the compression algorithm, but I think it is not a problem, because the zipfile module makes small chunks <= 16384.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tubing. Here's an example using s3, you could pretty easily create a rackspace clouldfile Source. Create a customer Writer (instead of sinks.Objects) to stream the data some where else and custom Transformers to transform the stream.

```
from tubing.ext import s3
from tubing import pipes, sinks
output = s3.S3Source(bucket, key) \
    | pipes.Gunzip() \
    | pipes.Split(on=b'\n') \
    | sinks.Objects()
print len(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out - it's part of the Python Standard Library:
http://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects

You can give it an open file or file-like-object.

Comment: Thanks @dstromberg, but it still doesn't solve the problem of writing a stream or a data iterator to the Zip file. The [`write`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) method still requires a filepath as the first argument.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10235749/288457) is close to what I need but it reads the whole image data and pass it to the [`writestr`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr) method, but this is impossible when the files are +100GB.